# Connect again failed issue

Tags: flutter, twilio, twilio-video

I am using Twilio-programable-video to make rtrc video connect by this library (twilio_programmable_video: ^1.1.1).

For now, everything is connecting fine other than connecting error happened or (push to same page and click connect again). The video is stuck, cannot not connect again other than quit the app and reopen it, it seems something amounted to the last connection. But I can't dispose it.

May I know does anyone have any idea about this?

I have tried to dispose the `_disposeStreamsAndSubscriptions || disableAudioSettings`, both seems not to work.

```
flutter: ConferenceRoom.connect()
flutter: [  NATIVE  ] PluginHandler::handle => received disableAudioSettings
flutter: [  NATIVE  ] PluginHandler::handle => received debug
flutter: [  NATIVE  ] AudioNotificationStreamHandler::onListen => AudioNotification eventChannel attached
flutter: [  NATIVE  ] PluginHandler::handle => received setAudioSettings
flutter: [  NATIVE  ] PluginHandler::setAudioSettings => called
flutter: [  NATIVE  ] PluginHandler::getAudioOptions =>
flutter:        bluetoothPreferred: true
flutter:        audioSettings.speakerEnabled: true
flutter: [  NATIVE  ] PluginHandler::applyAudioSettings =>
flutter:        mode: AVAudioSessionMode(_rawValue: AVAudioSessionModeVideoChat)
flutter:        options: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions(rawValue: 108)
flutter:        currentMode: AVAudioSessionMode(_rawValue: AVAudioSessionModeVideoChat)
flutter:        currentOptions: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions(rawValue: 4)
flutter: [  NATIVE  ] PluginHandler::applyAudioSettings => setActive
flutter: [  NATIVE  ] PluginHandler::handle => received CameraSource#getSources
flutter: [  NATIVE  ] AudioNotificationListener::handleRouteChange => notification: NSConcreteNotification 0x283a5dbc0 {name = AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification; object = <AVAudioSession: 0x283895460>; userInfo = {
flutter:     AVAudioSessionRouteChangePreviousRouteKey = "<AVAudioSessionRouteDescription: 0x2838859c0, \ninputs = (\n); \noutputs = (\n    \"<AVAudioSessionPortDescription: 0x28389e070, type = Speaker; name = \\U64f4\\U97f3; UID = Speaker; selectedDataSource = (null)>\"\n)>";
flutter:     AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey = 3;
flutter: }}
flutter: [  NATIVE  ] AudioNotificationListener::handleRouteChange => reason: 3, category: AVAudioSessionCategory(_rawValue: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
flutter: [  NATIVE  ] AudioNotificationListener::handleRouteChange => category: AVAudioSessionCategory(_rawValue: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
flutter: [   DART   ] Permissions => Microphone: PermissionStatus.granted, Camera: PermissionStatus.granted
flutter: [  NATIVE  ] PluginHandler::handle => received connect
flutter: [  NATIVE  ] PluginHandler::connect => called
flutter: [  NATIVE  ] PluginHandler::connect => setting roomName to 'test'
flutter: [  NATIVE  ] PluginHandler::connect => setting preferredAudioCodecs to '[<TVIOpusCodec: 0x283a5d060>]'
flutter: [  NATIVE  ] PluginHandler::connect => setting audioTracks to '[<TVILocalAudioTrack: 0x282f4a1c0>]'
flutter: [  NATIVE  ] PluginHandler::connect => setting dataTracks to '[<TVILocalDataTrack: 0x283453390>]'
flutter: [  NATIVE  ] PluginHandler::connect => setting videoTracks to '[<TVILocalVideoTrack: 0x2819c07d0>]'
flutter: [  NATIVE  ] PluginHandler::connect => setting enableNetworkQuality to 'true'
flutter: [  NATIVE  ] PluginHandler::getAudioOptions =>
flutter:        bluetoothPreferred: true
flutter:        audioSettings.speakerEnabled: true
flutter: [  NATIVE  ] PluginHandler::applyAudioSettings =>
flutter:        mode: AVAudioSessionMode(_rawValue: AVAudioSessionModeVideoChat)
flutter:        options: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions(rawValue: 108)
flutter:        currentMode: AVAudioSessionMode(_rawValue: AVAudioSessionModeVideoChat)
flutter:        currentOptions: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions(rawValue: 108)
flutter: [  NATIVE  ] PluginHandler::applyAudioSettings => setActive
flutter: ----------add _streamSubscriptions
flutter: ----------add _streamSubscriptions end ~~~
flutter: 6
flutter: [  NATIVE  ] AudioNotificationListener::handleRouteChange => notification: NSConcreteNotification 0x283a18220 {name = AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification; object = <AVAudioSession: 0x283885720>; userInfo = {
flutter:     AVAudioSessionRouteChangePreviousRouteKey = "<AVAudioSessionRouteDescription: 0x283876c70, \ninputs = (\n); \noutputs = (\n    \"<AVAudioSessionPortDescription: 0x283875880, type = Speaker; name = \\U64f4\\U97f3; UID = Speaker; selectedDataSource = (null)>\"\n)>";
flutter:     AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey = 3;
flutter: }}
flutter: [  NATIVE  ] AudioNotificationListener::handleRouteChange => reason: 3, category: AVAudioSessionCategory(_rawValue: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
flutter: [  NATIVE  ] AudioNotificationListener::handleRouteChange => category: AVAudioSessionCategory(_rawValue: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
flutter: [  NATIVE  ] AudioNotificationListener::handleRouteChange => notification: NSConcreteNotification 0x283a18220 {name = AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification; object = <AVAudioSession: 0x283895460>; userInfo = {
flutter:     AVAudioSessionRouteChangePreviousRouteKey = "<AVAudioSessionRouteDescription: 0x2838973f0, \ninputs = (\n    \"<AVAudioSessionPortDescription: 0x283896ec0, type = MicrophoneBuiltIn; name = iPhone \\U54aa\\U9ad8\\U98a8; UID = Built-In Microphone; selectedDataSource = \\U4e0b>\"\n); \noutputs = (\n    \"<AVAudioSessionPortDescription: 0x2838976d0, type = Speaker; name = \\U64f4\\U97f3; UID = Speaker; selectedDataSource = (null)>\"\n)>";
flutter:     AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey = 3;
flutter: }}
flutter: [  NATIVE  ] AudioNotificationListener::handleRouteChange => reason: 3, category: AVAudioSessionCategory(_rawValue: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
flutter: [  NATIVE  ] AudioNotificationListener::handleRouteChange => category: AVAudioSessionCategory(_rawValue: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
flutter: [  NATIVE  ] AudioNotificationListener::handleRouteChange => notification: NSConcreteNotification 0x283a33d20 {name = AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification; object = <AVAudioSession: 0x283885720>; userInfo = {
flutter:     AVAudioSessionRouteChangePreviousRouteKey = "<AVAudioSessionRouteDescription: 0x2838cdc90, \ninputs = (\n    \"<AVAudioSessionPortDescription: 0x2838cfc90, type = MicrophoneBuiltIn; name = iPhone \\U54aa\\U9ad8\\U98a8; UID = Built-In Microphone; selectedDataSource = \\U4e0b>\"\n); \noutputs = (\n    \"<AVAudioSessionPortDescription: 0x2838cf070, type = Speaker; name = \\U64f4\\U97f3; UID = Speaker; selectedDataSource = (null)>\"\n)>";
flutter:     AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey = 3;
flutter: }}
flutter: [  NATIVE  ] AudioNotificationListener::handleRouteChange => reason: 3, category: AVAudioSessionCategory(_rawValue: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
flutter: [  NATIVE  ] AudioNotificationListener::handleRouteChange => category: AVAudioSessionCategory(_rawValue: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
flutter: [   DART   ] Camera => Event 'FirstFrameAvailableEvent: { source: { cameraId: FRONT_CAMERA, isFrontFacing: true, isBackFacing: false, hasTorch: false } }'
flutter: [  NATIVE  ] PluginHandler::handle => received LocalDataTrack#sendString
flutter: [  NATIVE  ] PluginHandler::localDataTrackSendString => called for data_track-107ed9e3-523b-4d5c-ad06-47af9073ec23
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(NOT_FOUND, No LocalDataTrack found with the name 'data_track-107ed9e3-523b-4d5c-ad06-47af9073ec23', null, null)
#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:652:7)
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:310:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      ConferenceRoom.sendMessage (package:twilio_video/conference_room.dart:186:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
flutter: [  NATIVE  ] PluginHandler::handle => received LocalDataTrack#sendByteBuffer
flutter: [  NATIVE  ] PluginHandler::localDataTrackSendString => called for data_track-107ed9e3-523b-4d5c-ad06-47af9073ec23
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(NOT_FOUND, No LocalDataTrack found with the name 'data_track-107ed9e3-523b-4d5c-ad06-47af9073ec23', null, null)
#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:652:7)
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:310:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      ConferenceRoom.sendBufferMessage (package:twilio_video/conference_room.dart:195:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
```